# ReactJS using cookie while rendering on server side

Tags: reactjs, session-cookies

I am working on a web application and I used [this starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) as base of my project. The problem is that the cookie is not available in server side so I cannot use it for rendering a component in server.

I use [react-cookie](https://github.com/eXon/react-cookie) to save the account data after login

`cookie.save('account', accountData)`

and retrieve

`var account = cookie.load('account')`

it when I need it. I see that the cookie is saved into browser and I can use it in client side after the component is loaded but I need it in server side for pre-rendering operations.

So the question is how to achive that? Or, if cookie is not the right approach, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using the `cookie-parser` middleware? From the `react-cookie` docs:

> You can also plug it directly with a Node.js request by adding just before the renderToString:
>
> `reactCookie.plugToRequest(req, res);`
>
> **(require the cookieParser middleware)**

Express won't parse requests to get the cookie out unless you have some cookie parsing middleware installed and enabled in your Express app.