# How to avoid localStorage ReferenceError when server rendering with React Router

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build an universal webapp with react that is first run on the server and then the client takes over. 
I have the same code for client and server, and I'm trying to write some session tokens into localStorage but I hit

> ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined.

My guess is that theres no localStorage on the server side, and it blows the entire app

Is there any way I can use localStorage on client only? I have tried to make a simple check to proceed only if localStorage isnt undefined but it still ends up with a ReferenceError

Comment: Have you try to access the localStorage using `window.localStoarage`?

Comment: yeah, yeah I did, still no effect. I'm just wondering about the nature of this issue. If a client writes a token on the server, wouldnt then any other client connecting to the server get the same token? 
I'm afraid that storing user credentials in isomorphic app might not be as simple as writing to localStorage or cookies. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I opted out to choose cookies instead, after coming across this topic:
[ReactJS using cookie while rendering on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525483/reactjs-using-cookie-while-rendering-on-server-side)